# Multiprocessing with complex function

Tags: python, multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, joblib

I want to create a Multiprocess for a quite complex function in python:
I have tested this function with a less complex code like this:

```
from joblib import Parallel, delayed, parallel_backend
from joblib import load, dump

def print_hello(hallo, tschüß, rechnen,i):
    print(i)
    print(hallo[2])
    print (tschüß)
    rechnen = rechnen +i
    hallo2 = pd.DataFrame(hallo)
    hallo2.to_csv('./hallo'+str(i)+'.csv')
    hallo1 = pd.read_csv('./hallo'+str(i)+'.csv')
    return rechnen

hallo = ['hallo', 'hi', 'hey']
tschüß = 'tschüß'    
with parallel_backend('threading'):
test = Parallel()(delayed(print_hello)(hallo, tschüß, rechnen, i) for i in range(10))

print(test)
```

This is working quit nice. However i get the following Error-Code:

> joblib.my_exceptions.TransportableException: TransportableException
>
> ...
>
> joblib.my_exceptions.JoblibTypeError: JoblibTypeError
>
> ...
>
> TypeError: sum_row() missing 1 required positional argument: 'i'

When I want to make my complex function works, which looks like this:

```
def sum_row(count_series, path, folder, files_1, files_2, files_3, path_raw, i):
    print(i)
    df1 = pd.read_csv(path_raw + files_1[i], sep=',', low_memory=False)
    df2 = pd.read_csv(path_raw + files_2[i], sep=',', low_memory=False)
    df3 = pd.read_csv(path_raw + files_3[i], sep=',', low_memory=False)

    ##do some operations with those files and create df_test

    df_test.to_csv(path + folder + files_export[i])

    return 0

with parallel_backend('threading'):
    test = Parallel()(delayed(sum_row)(count_series, path, files_1, files_2, files_3,  path_raw, i) for i in range(len(files_1)))
```

Comment: you're missing the folder argument it seems when you call your function.

Comment: oh no...such a basic error, that did it, thank you.

Comment: no problem glad to help :)

Comment: @mgracer Do you somehow know why it is quite slow and just uses a small percentage of the CPU power? It is using many CPUs but all just a little bit?

Comment: use debugging tools to figure it out there are python modules for debugging performance

Comment: fyi --> use multiprocessing instead of threading as backend then it is working. And if there are more CPUs available than Jobs then it runs into a error so modify the n_job in Parallel() based on the count of your jobs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are getting the error is that you're missing the folder argument when calling the function.

```
test = Parallel()(delayed(sum_row)(count_series, path, folder, files_1, files_2, 
files_3,  path_raw, i) for i in range(len(files_1)))
```